# Inserir classe a um elemento invisível

Tags: jquery

Como faço para inserir uma classe via jQuery a um elemento que não está visível na página?

Comment: Da mesma maneira que você acrescenta a classe a um elemento visível :) Ele não precisa estar visível para ser manipulado, basta existir no documento. Se não existir, aí não tem como.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Para fazer uma boa pergunta leia [ask] e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Preciso inserir classes em linhas de uma tabela que compõem o retorno de um autocomplete, ou seja, a tabela não existe, quando digito um termo no campo de texto a tabela é criada com as sugestões.

Comment: E recebes essa tabela em que formato? HTML? isso vem via ajax do autocomplete? vem do teu servidor? podes detalhar mais?

Comment: as informações vem de um json

Comment: Montas a tabela no javascript com o JSON? ou é o autocomplete que monta a tabela?